# Control panel for Sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, plesk

n00b here

Is there some kind of control panel for Sphinx (to make things easier)?

Or is there a way I can use Plesk to handle it?

> I already installed (sphinx-0.9.9) on my CentOS, I
>   just don't know what to do next to index and search
>   on MySql (with php)

Also, can someone explain about using the daemon, api, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not that I know of.  Looks like you're stuck with your hands in the config files.

As for using Sphinx - as with any product, service, or platform, I'm afraid the most responsible answer is a friendly "RTM."  That said, it seems like you may want to [skip just a little ahead](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#quick-tour).